Send a struct composed of mulptiple structs each with a sortkey to dynamodb
When a user signs up I want to trigger a function to create a DynamoDB item with the user profile data. I want to use different sort keys for parts of this data. My object would look something like this:
type User struct {
    PersonalInfo   *PersonalInfo   `json:"personal_info"`
    Activity       *Activity       `json:"activity"`
    Preferences    *Preferences    `json:"preferences"`
    PrivacyAndData *PrivacyAndData `json:"privacy_and_data"`
    Others         *Others         `json:"others"`
}

Example of children structs:
type PersonalInfo struct {
    Sub         string `json:"sub"`
    SK          string `json:"SK"`
    PhotoUrl    string `json:"photo_url"`
    Email       string `json:"email"`
    Name        string `json:"name"`
    City        string `json:"string"`
    CompanyName string `json:"company_name"`
    Country     string `json:"country"`
}

What is the best way to put such item inside DynamoDB?
The solutions I found online seem very tedious, having to MarshalMap each field of the object separately like so:
func MarshalUserData(user *User) ([]map[string]types.AttributeValue, error) {
    avUserActivity, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(user.Activity)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    avUserPersonalInfo, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(user.PersonalInfo)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    avUserPreferences, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(user.Preferences)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    avUserPrivacy, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(user.PrivacyAndData)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    avUserOthers, err := attributevalue.MarshalMap(user.Others)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    slice := []map[string]types.AttributeValue{
        avUserActivity,
        avUserPersonalInfo,
        avUserPreferences,
        avUserPrivacy,
        avUserOthers,
    }
    return slice, nil
}

And then use a WriteBatch to send all data together. Which also has kinda sketchy code.
Is there any better alternative to this?

You say you want to create one item but DynamoDB BatchWriteItem is for writing multiple items. If you want cleaner code, I suggest the guregu/dynamo DynamoDB SDK wrapper. By the way, it's unclear what you mean by multiple sort keys. DynamoDB supports 0-1 range key per table, unless you count indexes.

I was aware I might have been unclear. So in theory I want to send one item but this item is composed of multiple tiny items each with its own sort key so I would have an structure similar to this: Partition key which is user sub, one sort key for UserActivity, one for PersonalInfo and so on, all of them under same partition key. Having in total 5 sort keys for this different types of data (all representing same user sub). Wanting to initialize everything on singup forces me to send all this separate items all at once using a BatchWriteItem and using this seemed very tedious.

@FinnBear Thanks for the advice though, I checked the library you provided and seems way more manageable.
